# Django Static Files Not Loading With Proven Proper Setup

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-staticfiles

I'm running Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10.  I work on a team of developers and something seems to have changed from yesterday to today and I can't seem to load static files locally with runserver.  We have a dev environment that is working fine.  All the other developers local environments are working fine.  Our production environment works fine.  We, as a team, are a bit stumped and hoped the community might be able to shed some light into the problem.

Here are the relevant portions of the project:

project.urls

```
if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve', {
            'show_indexes': True,
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

project.settings.dev

```
from __init__ import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
```

project.settings

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Project structure:

```
project
 --apps/
   --<dozens of apps>
 --settings/
   --__init__.py
   --dev.py
 --staticfiles/
 --templates/
 --__init__.py
 --manage.py
 --tests.py
 --urls.py
```

I've removed `project/static/` and run `manage.py collectstatic`, which copies 404 static files to `project/static/` from `project/staticfiles/`.

If I then run `manage.py runserver` I can see the site, but no static styles/files are loaded.

Note, nobody else seems to be having this problem.  We all use the same code base from Github.  There is literally no reason why I should be facing this problem while the others aren't.  Any ideas?  I'm considering just using Apache2 locally and setting up the .wsgi file and skipping the Django server altogether - but I'd really rather not.

Edit 1:
I noticed the Django server did complain a bit about some of the static files.

```
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:40] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:40] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8645
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:40] "GET /static/js/libs/less/less.js HTTP/1.1" 404 950
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:40] "GET /static/less/proton-app.less HTTP/1.1" 404 950
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:40] "GET /static/CACHE/js/987f5472f2f9.js HTTP/1.1" 404 950
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:41] "GET /static/CACHE/js/d5e323c0aed6.js HTTP/1.1" 404 950
[20/Feb/2013 16:59:41] "GET /static/images/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 950
```

My apologies.  Yes, there are some 404 errors associated with the static files.

Comment: What do the static file links say in the source of the HTML from the server? Are the links correct? Do the links 404? Permissions? There's a lot of debugging to be done on your end.

Comment: @DanHoerst The links are correct and files exist at those links (even the JS CACHE files).  There are no 404 or permission issues.  The site renders, but the static files are missing (styles, css, .less, etc)  I see a really ugly version of the site it's supposed to be.

Comment: Maybe you had been playing around with DEBUG=False? Static files are only served when DEBUG=True.

Comment: No, our dev settings are always DEBUG=True.  I think it has something to do with the database settings (Postgres not liking no host given when localhost) but I can't verify for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a code-based solution to this problem.  To fix this I deleted the project and deleted my virtual environment.  I then re-created my virtual environment, got my fork from github and re-setup the entire project environment.

Now it's working.  *shrugs*